# How do I add more spacing per item in my NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I can't seem to find a solution on how to add even more space between each item of my navigation drawer. Here is the image of what it looks like now.

[image: Here is the image].

I want to my items in my navigation drawer to have even more space in between. I tried **android:paddingTop** and **android:layout_marginTop** in my NavigationView of my activity.xml but it doesn't seem to work. How can I add more space between Items?

To help here is my code for my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Location.Location"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
   >

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer_menu"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="@android:color/transparent">
 </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It might help, here is my Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/homeNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Home"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_home_nav_drawer"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profileNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_profile_nav_drawer"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/topicsNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Topics"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_latest_news_black"
            />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/settingsNavigationDrawer"
            android:title="Settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
            />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more space between each item You can apply following Theme in your `styles.xml` for Navigation Drawer

```
style name="NavigationTheme" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
</style>
```

Apply this theme in Navigation Drawer

```
android:theme="@style/NavigationTheme"
```

Comment: the parent="AppTheme" is causing error.

Comment: AppTheme is your Base application theme, just you need to set your base theme name here